# Where does Web API store generated tokens in order to validate subsequent requests?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have a Web API and AngularJS client. The API is using default authorization provider given by visual studio to generate the token on token request with grant_type 'password'.

The AngularJS client is able to get the bearer token from Web API by calling the token endpoint with credentials and later passes this token to perform authorized requests in the API.

When AngularJS sends the token on any authorized API call, how is Web API able to validate the token? Where does the token get stored?

I checked in Identity tables in SQL server, I could not find any fields to store this token information. I checked in the configuration file, it is not stored there either. Could you please help me in understanding this concept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raj,

By default the token is not stored by the server. Only your client has it and is sending it through the authorization header to the server.

If you used the default template provided by Visual Studio, in the `Startup ConfigureAuth` method the following `IAppBuilder` extension is called: `app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions)`.

This extension coming from the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` package makes it easy for you to generate and consume tokens, but it is confusing as it is an all in one.
Behind the scene it's using two Owin middlewares:

- OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware: authorize and deliver tokens
- OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware: occurs at the `PipelineStage.Authenticate`, read the authorization header, check if the token is valid and authenticate the user.

To answer you questions WebAPI is able to validate the token thanks to the `OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware`, it will ensure that the token sent through the authorization header is valid and not expired. And the token is stored only by your client, if the client loose it, it will have to request a new one.

I advise you to get deeper in the OAuth protocol, and instead of using the extension `UseOAuthBearerTokens`, take a look at `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer` and `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication`, it will help you to better understand how it works.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. I am trying to find more information on OAuth2. 
you said 'OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware ensures that the token sent through the authorization header is valid and not expired'.Any idea what kind of validation is it? is it trying to sign the token with a key to validate it? Will I be able to use this validation in other webAPIs so that I can use the same bearer token without having to implement Authentication/Authorization part in every web api?

Comment: When your token is generated, it contains an expiration time, it carries its expiration time.

When the middleware un-protect the information contained in the token it will generate an `AuthenticationTicket` and check the expiration time.

By default it if you don't specify an 'AccessTokenFormat' it will use DPAPI (Data Protection API), it's built-in the OS and that's what used to protect the token. If you want to use the same token to be authorized on multiple Web API it will work if you are on the server. If it is not the case, it requires some work, and I advise you to look at JWT.

Comment: @Raj Did I answer your question?

Comment: apologies. Yes, pretty much answered my question.thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The generated token will most likely be a JWT ([Get Started with JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/)), which means it's a self-contained token that is signed with a secret/key that only the server or other trusted parties know.

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard ([RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object. **This information can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed.**

<sub>(emphasis is mine)</sub>

This means that **when receiving the token the server can ensure that**:

- the token was originally issued by a trusted party by checking that the signature is valid.
- the token is associated with a user that has permissions to perform the following request because the token itself contains information that uniquely identifier that user.

This type of approach **has the side-benefit that the server does not need to keep track or store the generated tokens in order to validate them at a later time**. Since no one else has the secret/key you can't modify the token without making the signature component invalid, which would then mean a faked token would end up being rejected by the server.

This is a simplified description of what happens, there are much more details around how to issue and validate tokens correctly. You should read the [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) specification to learn more on the subject of token-based authentication.

---

Also note that I assumed a JWT token because it's the format that currently has the most widespread adoption to accomplish scenarios like these ones and it's also the token format to use in conjunction with OAuth2 and OpenID Connect. However, it's still possible to achieve the same with other token formats.